# Cross Platform Open Source Projects

Tags: source-code, software-development

All open-source projects I have come across so far appear to be cross-platform, such as VLC, GIMP, and OpenOffice. All of this software is able to be run on multiple devices, including Windows and Mac OS X.

Do open source projects always run on multiple platforms and architectures?

So my question is: "**Can open-source projects be not cross-platform?**"

Comment: This question is quite broad, possibly too much so for this site. You're essentially asking for a list of software, a list which couldn't possibly be complete and would constantly change. See [here](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in our help centre for some guidance on good questions here.

Comment: Of course there are. You're just looking at the biggest and most popular FLOSS projects, where a lot of people have put in a lot of work to make them run on multiple OSes.

Comment: @TimMalone I somewhat disagree. It's really asking whether it is possible or not, and it's not explicitly asking for a list.

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's been edited since then - looks better now :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, open source projects can be platform-constrained. Look at the various [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org) projects for some examples; many of them only work on DOS PCs. There are many other examples of Windows-only projects, Linux-only projects (even Linux-only projects that work on a single architecture), AmigaOS-only projects...

Of course with a free software license there's nothing to stop people from porting projects to other platforms!